# WHERE clause for days between first day of month till today

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to write a query for a report to show the monthly consumption of spares and show it in a dashboard. How to write a `WHERE` clause for the date to capture the records from the day 1 of the current month till today.

Comment: Please specify database you use (SQL Server, DB2, Oracle etc..). Date-arithmetic is vendor-specific feature

Comment: The database used is SQL Server and the column name is job_cost.transaction_date

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clause below probably solves the problem

```
WHERE yourdate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL server is `SQL server 2012` , you can use `EOMONTH` which returns last day of month containing a given date.

Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) for more detail of using `EOMONTH`

To check your version of SQL server:

```
select @@VERSION
```

Here is what you want:

```
select * from  job_cost
Where transaction_date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)) and CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first day of month, using DATEFROMPARTS and get all values >= that datetime value.

```sql
-- Getting first day of month
DECLARE @StartOfMonth datetime = (SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Getdate()), MONTH(Getdate()), 1))

SELECT * from Tablename where deltaColumnName >= @StartOfMonth
```